# changing positions of sql query results

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, case

The title is not claryifying my problem but this is how i could describe it.

I have a query which returns the following result :

[image]

and i was wondering if there is a way to reduce the number of lines from three to one having all the three no null values ( 400, 1000 and 21820 in one line ) with banquet as description.

Thank you for reading.

PS: this is just a capture of a part of the query results and there are a lot of duplicated lines. i can post my query if it would be helpful. i'm using some select case there..

EDIT:

THANK YOU guys but i solved that by copying the results of the main query to input of another one and adding distinct and sum clauses

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT description, MAX(number1) AS number1, MAX(number2) AS number2)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY description
```

Answer (score 0):

At last in Oracle, you can use "When"
Eg:

```
SELECT 
DESCRIPTION,
CASE WHEN SUMPRICE1 IS NULL THEN
    CASE WHEN SUMPRICE2 IS NULL THEN
        CASE WHEN SUMPRICE3 IS NULL THEN
            0
        ELSE SUMPRICE3 END
    ELSE SUMPRICE2 END
ELSE SUMPRICE1 END AS SUMPRICE
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY DESCRIPTION, SUMPRICE
```

Off course this is useble just if you have a static number of columns.

**EDIT:** I think I don't get the problem, but, if you don't want to merge the columns, you can use:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION,
MAX(SUMPRICE1) AS SUMPRICE1,
MAX(SUMPRICE2) AS SUMPRICE2,
MAX(SUMPRICEN) AS SUMPRICEN
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY DESCRIPTION
```

Or you can use the case to avoid the null, in the case of any of rows don't have a value:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION,
CASE WHEN MAX(SUMPRICE1) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE WHEN MAX(SUMPRICE1) END AS SUMPRICE1,
CASE WHEN MAX(SUMPRICE2) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE WHEN MAX(SUMPRICE2) END AS SUMPRICE2,
CASE WHEN MAX(SUMPRICEN) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE WHEN MAX(SUMPRICEN) END AS SUMPRICEN
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY DESCRIPTION
```